# Máscara com Jquery alterando de fixo para celular ou vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

Tenho uma máscara JQuery para telefone, dependendo do tanto de informações que o usuário digitar eu entendo se é celular ou telefone fixo.
A máscara para fixo: **(55)9999-9999**
para celular:  **(55)99999-9999**
o código da máscara:

```
$("#Telefone").keydown(function () {
var tamanho = $("#Telefone").val().length;
if (tamanho <= 13) {
    $("#Telefone").mask("(99)9999-9999");
} else if (tamanho > 13) {
$("#Telefone").mask("(99)99999-9999");
}});
```

O problema e que funciona apenas a parte do fixo, quando a variável tamanho ultrapassa o valor 13 ele não deixa mais inserir valores no *input*, mesmo invertendo o código colocando o *tamanho > 13* antes, tem como fazer essa comparação? ou alguma outra solução.
obs.: utilizo o plug-in JQuery mask.

Comment: Diego Braga a resposta do @VirgilioNovic não atendeu a sua dúvida?

Comment: A resposta do @usuario se encaixou melhor no que eu necessitava, a do Virgilio também deu certo.

Comment: Isso, eu considero a melhor resposta, além disto os votos que ela recebeu demonstram isso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Exemplos:***

[jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var SPMaskBehavior = function (val) {
    return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-00009';
  },
  spOptions = {
    onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
        field.mask(SPMaskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
      }
  };

  $('#tel').mask(SPMaskBehavior, spOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel">
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
$("input.telefone").focusout(function() {
    var phone, element;
    element = $(this);
    element.unmask();
    phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (phone.length > 10) {
        element.mask("(99) 99999-9999");
    } else {
        element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
    }
}).trigger('focusout');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

Telefone: <input type="text" class="telefone" />
```

Comment: Apareceu uma interrogação no teste...

Comment: @LCarvalho Sim. ela aparece somente quando esta digitando. tira o focus do campo para você ver

Comment: Há um erro na lógica aí, a proposta do Virgilio Novic saiu-se melhor esteticamente.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra possível solução, ao invés de comparar o tamanho seria a seguinte:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.tipo').change(function(){
    var campo = $(this).val();
    if (campo == "fixo"){ 
      $("#Telefone").val('');
      $("#labelTelefone").html('Fixo');
      $("#Telefone").mask("(99)9999-9999");
    }
    else if (campo == "celular"){
      $("#Telefone").val('');
      $("#labelTelefone").html('Celular');
      $("#Telefone").mask("(99)99999-9999");
    }   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="radio" class="tipo" name="tipo_telefone" value="fixo">Fixo<br>
<input type="radio" class="tipo" name="tipo_telefone" value="celular">Celular<br><br>
<label id="labelTelefone">Telefone</label><input type="text" id="Telefone">
```

Answer (score -2):

Após procurar bastante (em 2020)

Consegui fazer funcionar da seguinte forma

```
$('#Telefone').mask("90000-0000")
```

Pois 0 é número obrigatório e 9 é opcional.

Answer (score -3):

```
const phoneOptions = {
"onKeyPress": (val, e, field, options) =>
    field.mask(
        (val) => val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? "(00) 00000-0000" : "(00) 0000-00009",
        options)
};
$("#telephone").mask("(00) 00000-0000", phoneOptions);
```